# Calibration Curve Error

Tags: scikit-learn, probability-calibration

I want to calibrate probability outputs of a model. I'm using Isotonic Regression. After calibration, when I called calibration_curve function of sklearn calibration module I got this error: ValueError: 'list' argument must have no negative elements. However when I checked results that I obtain from Isotonic Regression there are no negative values and all values are in [0,1] range. There are no problems in targets too.

```
from sklearn.isotonic import IsotonicRegression

i_reg = IsotonicRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
res = i_reg.predict(X_test)
prob_true, prob_pred = calibration_curve(y_test, res, n_bins=200, strategy="quantile")
```

Error log:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-5a2bd10e64b2> in <module>
----> 1 prob_true_model_test , prob_pred_cal_test = calibration_curve(y_test, res, n_bins=200, strategy="quantile")

/environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

/environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in calibration_curve(y_true, y_prob, normalize, n_bins, strategy)
    590     binids = np.digitize(y_prob, bins) - 1
    591 
--> 592     bin_sums = np.bincount(binids, weights=y_prob, minlength=len(bins))
    593     bin_true = np.bincount(binids, weights=y_true, minlength=len(bins))
    594     bin_total = np.bincount(binids, minlength=len(bins))

<__array_function__ internals> in bincount(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: 'list' argument must have no negative elements
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without your data.  I'd comment this, but it's a bit long and better formatted as an answer.

The part of the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf39bbdacd6ed713c00724f8f871d60370/sklearn/calibration.py#L564) that's relevant is quite short, so you can go through step by step to see what's wrong:

```py
bins = np.linspace(0., 1. + 1e-8, n_bins + 1)
binids = np.digitize(y_prob, bins) - 1
bin_sums = np.bincount(binids, weights=y_prob, minlength=len(bins))
```

`digitize` can return 0 if an element is to the left of all the bins; that shouldn't happen here, but maybe some computational precision error has crept in?  Check what values you get for `binids` above.

See also [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51617740/10495893), where NaNs were the culprit.